# craco-plugin-scoped-css not working on react.js css

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, craco

I m using react.js
My problem is that css on one component is coming on other component. so to try and fix it I tried using craco-plugin-scoped-css
craco-plugin-scoped-css is not working for some reason for me, heres what I did to install:
I first ran npm i craco-plugin-scoped-css
then created craco.config.js inside src folder and pasted:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
      { 
        plugin: require('craco-plugin-scoped-css')
      }
    ]
  }
```

I renamed my home.css and contact.css to home.scoped.css and contact.scoped.css, but for some reason, css is contact.scoped.css is overlaping css on home.scoped.css

I tried to add craco-plugin-scoped-css outside of src which didnt work

Edit: I would like to share that There is a main file, a header and a footer a main page file. and I m trying to add the styles to main file but instead its syncing the classes from footer file